# Second Order Ordinary Differential Equation with Unknown Scalar y(t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm given $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}(t) + (\sqrt{1+y^2}-2)\frac{dy}{dt}(t) + y(t) = 0$, and that $y(t)$ is a solution to the above, constant such that $y(t) = c$.  I need to solve for $c$ but I'm not sure where to start. How would I rewrite the ODE as a system of first-order equations?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to.   Asuming that's a solution, that means that if you take the second derivative, the first derivative, and the function itself,  and plug it into that equation, it makes the equation true

So $y(t)=c$,$y'(t)=0$,$y''(t)=0$. Plugging those in to the original equation, we have 
$0+(\sqrt {1+y%^2}-2)0+c=0$,  hence $c=0$

Thus the only constant solution that works is $y(t)=0$